# Relational operators and variables

Tags: c, floating-point, integer

```
#include<stdio.h>    
int main(void)
{
    int x = 3;
    float y = 3.0;

    if (x == y)
        printf("x and y are equal\n");
    else
        printf("x and y are not equal\n");
    return 0;
}
```

As per the mathematics, both are equal!

How does the compiler recognize both are equal? 
**(I am totally new to programming sorry if anything is wrong in my question)**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the computer all numbers are binary so: `0000 0011 == 0000 0011`

Comment: Because your code if statement is implicitly equivalent to `if ((float)x == y) { ... }`.

Comment: @Rizier123: I'm not sure what binary has to do with this.  `float` and `int` have different representations.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I wanted to say that the computer doesn't know what 13 or 23.45 is. The computer only works with 0 and 1

Comment: The compiler doesn't recognize anything. The compiler creates a set of machine instructions that your machine executes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler will do the conversion, and then do the comparison. In this particular situation both sides are converted to a floating point type.

Comment: I think both sides will be promoted to `double`. And also, the comparison may fail.

Comment: @haccks no, the right operand will stay as a `float` and the left operand will be converted to `float`.

Comment: @haccks: the relevant rule in the usual arithmetic conversions is [expr]/(10.4): "if either operand is `float`, the other shall be converted to `float`."

Comment: @KerrekSB; Then what about conversion of `float` to `double` ?

Comment: @haccks: that's a *promotion*, e.g. when you pass an argument through an ellipsis. That's something else, though (cf. *default argument promotions*).

Comment: @KerrekSB; Well, I agree that comparison will not fail but now I am interested in promotion. So, will it be promoted to `float` or `double`?

Answer (score 0):

int x=3 ;
The above variable x is stored as normal binary format i.e. 0000 0011, because of int

float y=3.0 ;
the above variable y is stored in IEEE 754 floating point format. i.e the value y is stored in a memory location with three different groups with sign bit, exponent and mantissa

here compiler will generate a executable file and it will add information about the two variables such that x variable is a integer type and y variable is float type. 
So, when it is stored in memory for execution those variables are stored as per the compiler's executable file suggests.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler will convert one of the two variables to the other type, let's say y to int, now both are of same type and can be compare.

The next step is an internal subtraction of both value and a test for the ZERO flag. If both values are equal, the subtraction result will 0 which causes the ZERO flag to be set.

Comment: Nope; the C Standard requires the int to be converted to float. There's also no ZERO flag in C.

Comment: @Jens Yes, C converts x to float, but not every language does this! My Answer is a common answer on how compilers solve this issue (as the OP asked). If you want to, you can also access flags in C! Normally these mechanisms are hidden from programmers, but again I explained in a common way, how the equal relation is handled in the underlying ISA.